# How to edit the hyperlink in excel to open both .doc and .docx versions

Tags: excel, hyperlink

The hyperlinks in excel are currently pointing out to .DOCX VERSION of the document

`https://xyz.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/sites/xyzteam/Shared%20Documents/General/XYs,%20YZs/1000012345.docx?&web=1`

Actually, the document in Sharepoint is in `.doc` version. So it results in 404 Error.

How would I modify the hyperlink to open either `.DOC` or `.DOCX` VERSIONS of document?

Would it be better to update the hyperlinks in excel (~100 in number) with the link or SHould I convert the documents from .DOC to .DOCX? Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify the hyperlinks in your excel. Because they are pointing to the original document.

Changing the format of the original documents just to satisfy the link requirements is not a good practice.

For changing the links, the easy way is that you can use the functionality of find and replace. You would need to find all the **.docx** and replace them with **.doc**.

This would be easy way to go.

Comment: Hey Minal, Thank you for your quick response. Yes, I will modify the hyperlinks. Only challenge here is few of the documents are .doc format and few in .docx format. If I'm giving and find and replace .docx with .doc, it would not help the cause.